# Using https instead of http with redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, https

In my controller i have

```
redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Product created'
```

This works correctly if i use http as the protocol. But the server where the application is deployed is using https. How can i make the redirect_to use https on the server but still continue to use http on my development machine ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In config/environments/production.rb add the following:

```
YourApp::Application.configure do
  ...
  config.force_ssl = true
end
```